# Stuck at Hidden Blade Cutscene

Tags: assassins-creed-2

Assassin's Creed 2 gets stuck at the cut-scene where:

> Leonardo DiVinci repairs your hidden blade, just as you get it.

I can open the map, options dialog, and change weapons but the cut-scene will not proceed.

I have tried replaying this memory several times, but it does not help.

I am running AC2 on Steam via UPlay (Windows 7, SP1, 64 bit). This is a legit copy.

Googling around suggests some others are having issues with this scene as well, but the issues seem to be with pirated copies only.

Comment: Your using the current version and not using a modified version of the exe right?

Comment: Yes. Latest version as of last night, updated by Steam. No mods to the game.

Comment: What video card do you have? Have you updated drivers recently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Press `2` on the keyboard. For some reason they don't want you to use the wheel to select the blade.